# Raid 1 Failed - Primary disk 1 dead, not booting from the mirrored one

Tags: linux, centos, raid, software-raid, raid1

We have a server mounted using Raid-1, using two disk of 1tb each, and configured by software on Centos. 
First disk (let's call it **sdb**) is dead and we took it away to replace it in a near future, while we decided to boot up the server using the mirrored disk **sda**. The thing is the system doesn't boot. it's stay in a black screen after the bios init screen. **my thoughts on this is that they didn't configure the mirrored disk to mirror the startup sector of the sdb**

i used a live ubuntu cd to boot the machine, and inspect the disk. My second thought is that it lacks the **MBR**, since when i looked into **sda** i saw a partition **sda1** and **sda2**, where the first has **10gb** of space, which i couldn't access. and then the second partition **sda2** which has the remaining **990gb** left, which is the partition that i'd need to boot since is the one with the server files and configurations

apart of this, i saw that **sdba** has all the system folders, such as **/boot /proc /bin ... etc etcc**

i've red that this **MAY** be solved installing the grub boot loader into the disk and then it may run. but i have fear of this if it will work, because of the first partition of 10gb already created.
 Others forums said this is irrecuperable, in case this is true, is there a way where i format the sdb1 partition of 10gb and install an OS to boot up the secondary partition and all it's services ?

below here, i will put all the information that i gathered, also if you need some extra relevant information, i will gladly look for it and upload it

```
   root@PartedMagic># sfdisk -d /dev/sda 
//
# partition table of /dev/sda
unit: sectors

/dev/sda1 : start=     2048, size= 19529728, Id=fd
/dev/sda2 : start= 19531776, size=1933991936, Id=fd
/dev/sda3 : start=        0, size=        0, Id= 0
/dev/sda4 : start=        0, size=        0, Id= 0
```

---

```
root@PartedMagic>/media/md1/boot/grub# cat device.map
//
(hd0)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD1002FAEX-007BA0_WD-WMAY00918352
(hd1)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD1002FAEX-00Z3A0_WD-WCATRC581793
(hd2)   /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Kingston_DT_101_G2_00187D0F5670EC601000BFD3-0:0
```

---

```
/dev/md1:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed Oct 30 21:06:56 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 966864704 (922.07 GiB 990.07 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 966864704 (922.07 GiB 990.07 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Oct 25 17:34:47 2016
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : pbx1:1
           UUID : 87040663:7e96da33:d143c52d:63d27f4a
         Events : 6512040

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8        2        1      active sync   /dev/sda2
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed Oct 30 21:06:51 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 9756544 (9.30 GiB 9.99 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9756544 (9.30 GiB 9.99 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Oct 25 17:36:14 2016
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : pbx1:0
           UUID : 092582ab:c3cd6b70:98b1b939:a5bb67a7
         Events : 602

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8        1        1      active sync   /dev/sda1

------------------------------
root@PartedMagic>/media/md1/boot/grub# cat device.map
//
(hd0)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD1002FAEX-007BA0_WD-WMAY00918352
(hd1)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD1002FAEX-00Z3A0_WD-WCATRC581793
(hd2)   /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Kingston_DT_101_G2_00187D0F5670EC601000BFD3-0:0
```

---

This is the MDMADM.CONF file

```
CONFIGURACION MDADM.CONF
-------------------------------------------
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default, scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) for MD superblocks.
# alternatively, specify devices to scan, using wildcards if desired.
DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=092582ab:c3cd6b70:98b1b939:a5bb67a7 name=pbx1:0
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 UUID=87040663:7e96da33:d143c52d:63d27f4a name=pbx1:1

# This file was auto-generated on Wed, 06 Nov 2013 11:10:29 -0300
# by mkconf 3.1.4-1+8efb9d1+squeeze1
```

---

This is the cfg i found inside Grub conf:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod raid
insmod mdraid
insmod part_msdos
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(md/1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 307c9805-75d2-44d9-a411-465ae556d743
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=640x480
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
insmod raid
insmod mdraid
insmod part_msdos
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(md/1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 307c9805-75d2-44d9-a411-465ae556d743
set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
set lang=es
insmod gettext
set timeout=5
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod raid
    insmod mdraid
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(md/1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 307c9805-75d2-44d9-a411-465ae556d743
    echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-amd64 root=/dev/md1 ro  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-amd64
}
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod raid
    insmod mdraid
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(md/1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 307c9805-75d2-44d9-a411-465ae556d743
    echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-amd64 root=/dev/md1 ro single 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-amd64
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Any help will be appreciated, it's the first time i have to deal with an error of this nature , also one the first times approaching RAIDS.

THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

**Before you try anything make a clone of /dev/sda if you have a 3rd 1TB drive.

Just to be clear:

```
/dev/sda=Current/only drive in RAID
/dev/sdb=New drive
```

- Only connect /dev/sda & boot in rescue mode with the same distro
- `chroot` to sysimage and use `grub-install` to install it on /dev/sda.
  Remember you're installing it to the boot sector of your hard drive
  and not to a partition, so do not use a partition number like
  /dev/sda1
- Remove rescue USB/CD and reboot, if it boots (yay!) shut down and add /dev/sdb and reboot. Make sure BIOS is set to boot from /dev/sda first & /dev/sdb1 second.
- Wipe any partition from /dev/sdb1 with `fdisk` and mirror partitions from /dev/sda to /dev/sdb with `sfdisk`
- Used `mdadm` to add /dev/sdb1 partition to /dev/md0
- Dont forget to run `grub-install` on /dev/sdb, so you dont find yourself in
  this situation again :)

This link should help:
https://www.howtoforge.com/replacing_hard_disks_in_a_raid1_array